# Lucida font on command window not looking correct in regular size, okay when maximized

Tags: windows-xp, fonts

I rely on a DOS program for my writing.  I just ran combofix and the window now looks like `ansi.sys` is not working with the Lucida font. Although when I maximize the window, everything looks fine.

Any suggestions about how to fix it?